# Using monitor in UHD resolution, but keeping all Windows UI approx. the same visual size as it was in lower resolution?

Tags: windows-10, resolution, windows-11, 4k-resolution

I would like to buy a new monitor, capable for UHD resolution. I use my current monitor 1680x1050, its native resolution. (weird I know, it is old)

Supposing all my hardware capable to produce UHD@60Hz (either via hdmi v.2.0 or DisplayPort), my main concern is the Windows UI will be too small, or if I try to configure Windows 11 (which is the planned OS) it will do weird trick so either the resolution will not be real UHD, either the desktop or menus or fonts within the application will not be perfect, I mean it will be not a real scaling just partial tricks.

**Question**

Is there any correct way to using monitor in UHD resolution, but keeping all Windows (11) UI approx. the same visual size as it was in lower resolution?

*Additional info why I am asking this at all, can be ignored, skipped*

(Probably I did it incorrectly, but I had that experience with my other PC a multimedia PC which is connected to a Sony TV via hdmi 2.0, and when I tried to set the UI to 4K either the whole UI went crazy small or when I tried to configure to be bigger weird thing happened, and sometimes, it went back to Full HD. I am aware 4K and UHD not exactly the same, but that PC is a multimedia PC, the subject of my question is a desktop PC, where I planning to use a UHD monitor.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what Windows UI display scaling is intended to achieve. You get a much more crisp display, using the higher resolution, but with on screen elements more suited to the display physical size rather than resolution.

From [Lifewire: How to Use Windows 10 Display Scaling](https://www.lifewire.com/using-windows-10-display-scaling-4587328)

> #### How to Turn on Display Scaling in Windows 10
>
> - Go to the Windows Start Menu.
> - Choose Settings.
> - Select System.
> - Select Display.
> - Look for the Change the size of text, apps, and other items under Scale and layout. Select an option, such as 125% or 150%. ...
> - Your display will re-size.

Fonts, icons, and so on will be scaled up by the percentage you set.  Old applications that do not support scaling may look odd or small, but many applications released in the last few years should support it.

Comment: Came here to post pretty much the same answer. This is exactly the solution to your problem!

Comment: Many thanks. I will go for the new monitor (and a machine which supports UHD@60Hz then give it a shot with Windows 11.

Comment: Windows 11 does have the same scaling engine, and it works the same as Windows 10. It is also more or less in the same settings area: https://www.elevenforum.com/t/change-display-dpi-scaling-level-in-windows-11.934/